# Cannot find where the content of my adapter is being modified from a background process

Tags: android, listview

Everyday I get atleast 1 report of my app crashing due to my list adapter being modified from a background thread but I cannot find where in the class this is happening.

What can I do to find where this issue is? the stack trace does not help.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has
>   changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the
>   content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but
>   only from the UI thread. [in ListView(2131165368, class
>   android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class
>   com.xxx.xx.xx.xxListAdapter)] at
>   android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1538) at
>   android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3524) at
>   android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7127) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2170)
>   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1905) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
>   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1919) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
>   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1919) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
>   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1919) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
>   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1919) at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1930)
>   at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1384)
>   at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2402) at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1878)
>   at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7307) at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3184)
>   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3129)
>   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4165)
>   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4144)
>   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4236)
>   at
>   android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:171)
>   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method) at
>   android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4781) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:3152)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:2919) at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Please do not use the quote symbol for stack trace formatting but the normal "code" indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, your list adapter is getting modified from your background thread, the reason is you are calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` inside the background thread not in main UI thread,
The solution is moving it to UI thread or simply wrapping it with runOnUiThread():

```
......
     runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
         { 
            public void run() 
                {
                   notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
         });
... ...
```

Hope this will help you.